# React Native Text input icon not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am very new with react native and as part of my trial app development I am trying to create a form for registration.

Here is the [snack](https://%3Cdiv%20data-snack-id=%22@sforsandeep/textinput.icon%22%20data-snack-platform=%22android%22%20data-snack-preview=%22true%22%20data-snack-theme=%22light%22%20style=%22overflow:hidden;background:#F9F9F9;border:1px%20solid%20var(--color-border);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%25%22%3E%3C/div%3E%20%3Cscript%20async%20src=%22https://snack.expo.dev/embed.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Here as you can see I am trying to use the react native paper for textinput. But the icon is not at all showing even there is space for icon is showing.

[image]

I thought its the problem with simulator in snack, but when trying the same in phone using expo, its not showing the icon.

Please help

```
<TextInput
      mode="outlined"
      label="Email"
      onChangeText={(email) => setFullName(email)}
      style={styles.TextInput}
      left={
        <TextInput.Icon name="account" size={24} color="#fff" />
      }
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using an `icon` attribute there:

```
<TextInput left={<TextInput.Icon icon="account"/>}/>
```

It looks like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. It straight away resolved the problem.